# How can I be sure each process in my mongrel_cluster is handling requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, mongrel-cluster

I have a rails application that takes a while to process certain requests (as it processes image uploads).  I currently have three mongrel processes in a cluster, and I expect one of the other two to handle a second request if the first one is busy.

However, this doesn't seem to be happening.  If I watch the output from `top` on the server, I can tell when it is resizing an image, so if I try to hit the application with an easy request (which would normally finish quickly), it seems to wait until the long-running request in finished.

When I look in the log/mongrel.xxxx.log files, all I see is the output from the application starting up.

How can I verify which process is actually handling each request?

Can I get them mongrels to log each request (even if it is just a timestamp, and something like 'GET /path/to/resource')?

Any ideas why the cluster might not be sharing the load in the first place?

The front-end web server is nginx, so maybe that is where I should be looking?  The nginx access_log doesn't seem to have anything in it about where the request was proxied to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We encountered similar issues on [reevoo.com](http://www.reevoo.com) some time ago. Have a look at the [resultant blog post](http://www.reevoo.com/labs/2008/07/fixing-uneven-load-balancing-between-apache-and-mongrel-for-ruby-on-rails-applications/).

Of specific interest is the use of [mongrel_proctitle](http://alexstaubo.github.com/mongrel_proctitle/) to diagnose the issue. It will allow a `ps aux` to see what a specific mongrel is handling.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me the information I needed. (Unfortunately, it wasn't the information I wanted, but that's another story :)